# Comparación de strings por defecto en C#. No diferenciar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: c#

En repetidas ocasiones debo comparar strings y por defecto C# es sensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas, de modo que que lo siguiente no funcionamiento

```
string nombre = "AlgunaCosa";
nombre.Contains("alguna");
```

Al final siempre acabo comparando minúsculas

```
nombre.ToLower().Contains("alguna");
```

¿Existe alguna directiva para que de forma global la comparación de strings en C# no tenga en cuenta las mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No existen directivas globales que gestionen la comparación de cadenas pero tienes varias opciones. Te propongo algunas:

- Usar `IndexOf` con la opción `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

  ```
  bool contiene= nombre.IndexOf("alguna", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
  ```
- Crear un método de extensión para `Contains`:

  ```
  public static bool ContainsIC(this string cadena, string cadenaBusqueda)
  {
      return cadena.ToLower().Contains(cadenaBusqueda.ToLower());
  }
  ```

  Uso:

  ```
  string nombre = "AlgunaCosa";
  var contiene = nombre.ContainsIC("alguna");
  ```
- Usar [`string.Compare(string,string,bool)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_):

  ```
  var contiene=string.Compare(nombre, "alguna", true)>-1;
  ```

---

Tras investigar un poco, parece que no se recomienda usar `ToLower` o `ToUpper` dado que dependiendo del idioma puede dar resultados inesperados, además de que tiene el sobrecoste de crear una nueva cadena. Así que podríamos modificar el método de extensión propuesto anteriormente por el siguiente:

```
public static bool Contains(this string fuente, string aComparar, StringComparison comp)
{
    return fuente?.IndexOf(aComparar, comp) >= 0;
}
```

Para usar el null check `?` deberemos estar usando C# 6 o superior. Si no fuera asi, podemos cambiar el código por

```
if (source == null) return false;
return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
```

Modo de uso:

```
bool contiene = nombre.Contains("alguna", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

<sub>Este último código está tomado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/</sub>